# Is it possible to write what I am searching for in the Select part?

Tags: mysql, sql, ip

I am using the following query, but I would like that for every entry I have in the WHERE clause, I get a result even for those that are in the same subnet. In my case if two IPs are in the same subnet, the result is returning one tuple. I would like that for every IP I have, a tuple is retuned. Can someone please help?

```
SELECT name, ipstart ,prefix , <ip_seached_for>
FROM ip 
JOIN countries
ON      ip.sid = countries.sid WHERE (
        (INET_ATON('125.235.51.241') between ipstartdec and ipenddec) OR
        (INET_ATON('125.235.51.200') between ipstartdec and ipenddec) OR
        (INET_ATON('116.79.199.160') between ipstartdec and ipenddec)
        )
```

**Table Structure:**

```
**IP**                      
sid ipstart prefix  ipend   maskdec ipstartdec  ipenddec
2   79.106.255.64   28  79.106.255.79   4294967280  1332412224  1332412239
4   194.158.95.192  28  194.158.95.207  4294967280  3265159104  3265159119
4   194.158.95.208  28  194.158.95.223  4294967280  3265159120  3265159135
4   194.158.95.224  27  194.158.95.255  4294967264  3265159136  3265159167


**Countries**   
SID Name
2   Albania
3   Algeria
4   Andorra
5   Aruba
6   Argentina
7   Argentina
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data from the `ip` and `counries` (`countries`?) table. Also, the `ip` tag is inappropriate here, as are the `search` and `join` tags. From your usage of the `INET_ATON` I assume you are using `mysql`, so it would be appropriate to tag with `mysql`. Please fix the tags appropriately.

Comment: thanks Zev ... I edited the SQL accordingly. Yes I am using mysql.

Comment: But you still haven't provided any sample data.

Comment: sorry I missed that. Tables added. What I would like is that if 2 IPs are shown in the same subnet, I would like to have two tuples, each having the IP i am searching for (i.e. <ip_seached_for> in Select statment)

Comment: @mouthpiec can you put up your expected output from this please